# Should I ignore .bash_rc, .bash_profile etc if I'm using Zsh?

Tags: macos, bash, zsh

[Zsh](http://www.zsh.org) configs go into the `~/.zshrc` file. That’s where I’ve been putting my aliases, etc…

But I want to know if I should be ignoring `.bash_profile` and those other files, and putting everything into the `.zshrc` file? A lot of instructions online for installation or system set-up stuff have me adding stuff to `.bash_rc`, etc. I assume if I’m into using Zsh, I should be putting that stuff in `.zshrc`?

I’m doing mainly front end web development, not hosting any web servers and I’m not a CLI genius or anything.

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to know if I should be ignoring `.bash_profile` and those
>   other files, and putting everything into the `.zshrc` file? A lot of
>   instructions online for installation or system set-up stuff have me
>   adding stuff to `.bash_rc`, etc. I assume if I’m into using `zsh`, I
>   should be putting that stuff in `.zshrc`?

This [webpage explains the differences nicely](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/), but it basically boils down to exactly what you are stating; if you are using [Zsh](http://www.zsh.org) then just place your adjustments/settings in the equivalent Zsh file:

- [**Zsh**](http://www.zsh.org): Only cares about `.zshenv`, `.zprofile`, `.zshrc`, `.zlogin` and `.zlogout`.
- [**Bash**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/): Only cares about `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile` and `.bash_logout`.

So if you are reading any only tutorials or guides that refer to adding items to `.bash_profile`—since tons of users use `bash` by default—you then should just add those items to `.zprofile` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the “right way”  but a `ln -s` them so in the event I need to

1. Use bash for scripting.
2. New installs without `zsh` or if `zsh` goes “dead in the water” I have a backup.

But in my experience they are mutually exclusive to their respective shells